# MVC project uses Web API project inside same Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to learn more about Docker in my free time. I am currently trying to get ASP.NET Identity Server to work with it.

Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Download: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity
2. Run the ASP.NET MVC client application and the server application and browse to the following URL to make sure it is working properly: http://localhost:5002/Home/CallApiUsingClientCredentials

   The code looks like this:

   ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> CallApiUsingClientCredentials()
   {
           var tokenClient = new TokenClient("http://localhost:5000/connect/token", "mvc", "secret");
           var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api1");

           var client = new HttpClient();
           client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
           var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/identity");

           ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(content).ToString();
           return View("Json");
   }
   ```

   I get the response I am expecting.
3. Right click on the API project and select Add Container Orchestration Support.
4. Right click on MVCClient and select: Add/Container Orchestration Support.

Docker Compose Override then looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mvcclient:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5002:80"

  api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5001:80"


  identityserverwithaspnetidentity:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
```

Make changes to the code above as follows:

Line 3 change to:

```
var tokenClient = new TokenClient("http://identityserverwithaspnetidentity:80/connect/token", "mvc", "secret");
```

Line 10 change to:

```
var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://api:80/Identity");
```

When I browse to http://localhost:5002/Home/CallApiUsingClientCredentials; I am receiving a weird response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=http://www.webaddresshelp.bt.com/main?ParticipantID=mg76cjr54t8kx45jjw4j4k9j5hsr5m26&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fapi1%2FIdentity&FailureMode=1&Implementation=&AddInType=4&Version=pywr1.0&ClientLocation=uk\"/><script type=\"text/javascript\">url=\"http://www.webaddresshelp.bt.com/main?ParticipantID=mg76cjr54t8kx45jjw4j4k9j5hsr5m26&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fapi1%2FIdentity&FailureMode=1&Implementation=&AddInType=4&Version=pywr1.0&ClientLocation=uk\";if(top.location!=location){var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,b=d.body,x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||b.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||b.clientHeight;url+=\"&w=\"+x+\"&h=\"+y;}window.location.replace(url);</script></head><body></body></html>
```

What is the problem please?

**Update**

Why do the lines below return the output above (what I referred to as the weird response):

```
var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://bert:80/Identity");
var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://somerandomserver:80/Identity");
var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://hello:80/Identity");
```

bert; somerandomserver and hello do not exist.  It appears the response above is always received as long as I use port 80 i.e. regardless of the server name I use i.e. I can make it up.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For web apps in `docker compose`, they are sharing the same networks in the `Compose`.

Per to your steps, it seems you only changed the request URLs. You also need to change the `Authority` in api project.

Try to change `src\Api\Startup.cs` with below:

```
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://identityserverwithaspnetidentity:80";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
            });
```

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  I figured it out about an hour after I posted the question.  Do all the ports have to be 80?

Comment: Could you have a lok at my update before I accept - it was part of the otiginal question as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 could not reproduce your issue. I got `Couldn't resolve host name` with the invalidate hostname.

Comment: I notice there is a reference to www.webaddresshelp.bt.com in the JSON response (see JSON response).  Could my ISP (BT) be forwarding my request somewhere else on port 80 - if the URL is invalid? More about BT Address Help here: http://preferences.webaddresshelp.bt.com/selfcare/

Comment: @w0051977 How to reproduce your issue with [6_AspNetIdentity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity)

Comment: are you asking me a question?

Comment: Yes, I did not know how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Are you able to have a look at my other identity server question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872070/using-identity-server-inside-an-xamarin-app ? Thanks.