# Using Identity Server inside an Xamarin app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, identityserver4

I am trying to get an Xamarin app working with Identity server.  I have followed these steps:

1) Download this: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/XamarinForms
2) Run the Xamarin Forms app from point 1.  It works as expected i.e. I can login as Bob and I am authenticated against the public facing demo app: https://demo.identityserver.io

It works as expected up to here.

3) I then download the public facing demo app here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo.  Add it to the Xamarin solution.
4) In the solution; do a find and replace - from https://demo.identityserver.io to http://localhost:24997/ (this is the URL of my identity server inside the solution).

5) Comment out the following lines of code as I am not using Azure:

```
//Startup.cs
 //.AddGoogle("Google", options =>
                //{
                //    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                //    options.ClientId = Configuration["Secret:GoogleClientId"];
                //    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Secret:GoogleClientSecret"];
                //})
                //.AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Sign-in with Azure AD", options =>
                //{
                //    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                //    options.ClientId = "https://leastprivilegelabs.onmicrosoft.com/38196330-e766-4051-ad10-14596c7e97d3";

                //    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                //    options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                //    options.ResponseType = "id_token";
                //    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-aad";
                //    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-aad";
                //    options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-aad";

                //    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                //    {
                //        ValidateIssuer = false,
                //        ValidAudience = "165b99fd-195f-4d93-a111-3e679246e6a9",

                //        NameClaimType = "name",
                //        RoleClaimType = "role"
                //    };
                //})

//Program.cs
//.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
//{
//    var config = builder.Build();
//    var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
//    var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient((authority, resource, scope) => tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback(authority, resource, scope));
//    builder.AddAzureKeyVault(config["KeyVault:BaseUrl"], kvClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
//})
```

6) Add options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; to IdentityServer.Startup.

I then run the Xamarin app and the Identity server.  I see an error on the following line inside the Xamarin app (first line of: MainPage.Login_Clicked):

```
_result = await _client.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());
```

The error is: `Error connecting to http://localhost:24997/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Is there any more to the message? The code suggests that there might be an associated reason phrase. 2) What happens if you open the URL that's failing in the browser yourself?

Comment: 1) Inner exception says socket exception 2) I can see the webpage.  Could it be that the xamarin device cannot see localhost (identiy server).  Perhaps I need to browse to the IP address/domain name instead of localhost?

Comment: Yes, that sounds a likely cause. localhost means different things on the two different devices as I'm sure you know.

Comment: Tried that and it made no difference.  Followed my instructions again and got the same result.  Did you try follow my instructions.  What result did you get? Thanks again.

Comment: I haven't been able to follow your instructions as I don't have a Xamarin setup right now. I'll see if I can give it a try later when I have some time to play with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test this with multiple devices then you cannot use localhost. You will have to have both devices in the same network and use your local IP address instead.

For the IdSrv app, you need to configure the hosting URL properly, e.g. by changing the `launchSettings.json` if you are developing locally, or by setting the `ASPNETCORE_URL` environment variable. When you run the server application, it should tell you that it is listening on `http://192.168.1.101:5000` or whatever the local IP address and the selected port is.

You will then need to configure that as the authority URL in your Xamarin application. The app can then reach the identity server and properly communicate with it.

If the authentication doesn't work then, the server logs from the identity server should give you further details on what is going wrong. That way, you can tweak the client settings in the identity server, and the authentication settings in your Xamarin app, until everything works.